# How to know console error in chrome Kiosk mode

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kiosk-mode

I have a requirement to run my application in chrome kiosk mode, its working fine in normal mode. But when I start kiosk mode app using localhost URL or IIS server URL (Windows), it does not works properly.

A java-script code is unable to run in kiosk mode. I am trying using the following line of code:

```
            signOutButtonPressed();

            try {
                cwic.LoginController.startDiscovery();
            } catch (e) {
                PhoneDialing("Error: " + e);
            }
```

From this call I am unable to get this function call from third party APIs.
I am sure about this APIs are working when I hosted my code on IIS. I hope anyone must have an experience on same.

Comment: do you want to open `console` in kiosk mode ?

Comment: better if is possible, as I wanna know what errors coming over there ?

Comment: can you attach a keyboard with kiosk if yes F12 else you have to write a function to open console

Comment: I am using on screen keyboard from third party js thats mottie's keyboard. But could you please tell me how to open console using function ?

Comment: okay i too faced the same issue and used the same library
you might not be able to open the console but you can keep the track of your errors that comes up

Comment: `window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {  
  //save error and send to server for example.
  return true;
}; `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to see the errors, you can post the error in server but with kiosk it might be hard to open `console` with the virtual keyboard.
You can try 
[Sentry](https://sentry.io/welcome/)

Or

`window.onerror = function(message, url, lineNumber) {
//save error and send to server for example.
  return true;
};`

Comment: This helps me alot. Thanks

Comment: you can mark `tick` to my solution if it helped you